# Cannot connect to localhost/my_app while XAMPP working fine

Tags: xampp

I am trying to develop a CRUD app using `XAMPP` with Apache and mySQL running properly and PHP. I am writing my code in Sublime Text. For now i haven't done much, but I wrote 3 scripts and put a title. Now I want to connect to my `localhost/CRUD_App_PHP` but I cannot and I dont understand why.
Here is my code till now. It is in `index.php` which is the only file with something in it for now. I will create add,remove,`update.php` later. But for now I want to see that it works.

Here is what I get when accessing localhost/CRUD_App_PHP

[image]

And here is a photo of my Code [image]

Answer (score 1):

The error that you sent is from Microsoft IIS web server running on port 80. You shoulud change the Apache port to 88 or something else.
Than go to http://localhost:88/CRUD_App_PHP

Comment: No, it sould not. Port 3306 is for database.

Comment: well I dont see image without vpn so dont see what is error Tought he cant connect to mysql

Comment: He can connect to MySQL. His problem is that, it shows 404 error, when he goes to localhost/CRUD_App_PHP, but a IIS server is running on his computer too, so he must change the Apache port and open the page with that port.

Comment: I got the same problem when I upgraded my appserver all were runing php and mysql and mariaDB but I couldnt connect, I solved error including port=3308; into my connection and it worked for me, because mariaDB was default. 2 weeks ago, on windows 10, 3308 was showing on wamp tools as mysql port. and he is having same error as he mentioned all runing.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys, I really appreciate, apparently it was working just fine, all I needed was to use the port while connecting to localhost as told by CreeperMaxCZ. Thanks!